Umbraco - Trigger umbraco form workflow on new record entry
Umbraco Version 12.0
I use following code which helps me insert record in umbraco form, but even thought record gets approved but the workflow is still like 0/0.
public bool InsertFormData(Form form, object formModel   )
{
    try
    { 
        Record record = new Record();

        foreach (Field field in form.AllFields)
        {
            string caption = CleanCaption(field.Caption); 
            if (formModel.GetType().GetProperty(caption) == null) continue; 
            var propertyValue = formModel.GetType().GetProperty(caption).GetValue(formModel, null);

            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
                List<object> values = ExtractValues(propertyValue);

                RecordField recordField = new RecordField
                {
                    Alias = field.Alias,
                    FieldId = field.Id,
                    Field = field,
                    Key = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Record = record.Id,
                    Values = values
                };
                record.RecordFields.Add(recordField.Key, recordField);
            }
        } 
        record.Form = form.Id; 
        record.UmbracoPageId = -1;
        record.State = Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums.FormState.Submitted;
        record.RecordData = record.GenerateRecordDataAsJson(); 
        _recordStorage.InsertRecord(record, form); 
        _recordStorage.DisposeIfDisposable();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error : " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    } 
}

More:
In this form i just send email to form to subscribe for newsletter, after which i want to apply some workflow on record. but its not assigning workflow to record.

